# Evaluating Hall Effect Sensor - Practical Explanation of Bops / Brps?

Tags: hall-effect

I am trying to choose between two types of hall effect diodes with internal pull-up resistors.

What is the practical explanation when comparing the Bop and Brp of the types (red square):
 - AH3781 and AH3782?

Do the Bop and Brp of the hall effect sensor determine the sensitivity of the sensor?

[image]

Comment: App note: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slia086/slia086.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these values show the sensitivity of your sensor. The B is your magnetic flux density strength (in Gauss) and Bop is your operating point, and Brp is your release point. By the + and - values, I would think this has something to do with it sensing from their North and South poles.

Let's use the AH3781 as an example. Essentially, it looks like when the South pole reaches 25G, the sensor will switch on and go low (due to the internal pullup note, it is safe to assume that the output of this sensor is HIGH), then to switch it back OFF again, you will need 25G sensed on the North pole.

**Confirmation**

In fact, if you look at this [DATASHEET](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/DIOD/DIOD-S-A0001172457/DIOD-S-A0001172457-1.pdf), you will see I was correct. The important thing to note, is the *smaller* the number is, the *more sensitive* your sensor is.

Also, be aware of the direction of magnetic flux. Different sensors will detect on different axis. The datasheet will usually tell you, then you can figure out the best orientation for your sensor or magnet.